# Embedding $\mathbb{Z}$-modules into injective $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

I want to show that any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ can be embedded into an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module (I'm in the process of showing this can be done for more general rings, but starting with this case).

My idea is to tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$, so define $N=\mathbb{Q}\otimes M$. This is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module via $$n(q\otimes m)=q\otimes nm=nq\otimes m$$ and extending linearly.

It is divisible since $$\sum q_im_i=n\sum \frac{q_i}{n}m_i$$ Now, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID and for a module over a PID injectivity is equivalent to divisibility, so $N$ is injective, and $M$ embeds via $m \rightarrow (0,m)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The problem is that $M\to \mathbb{Q}\otimes M$ is not necessarily injective. Think of the case $M=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The result is indeed divisible, but the map is not injective in general. Consider the case of a finite cyclic group: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q} = 0$.

For a proof, consider a presentation of your abelian group: $G = \mathbb{Z}\langle S \rangle / R$, where $R \subset \mathbb{Z}\langle S \rangle$ is an abelian group (necessarily normal). Then consider the quotient of abelian groups $I = \mathbb{Q}\langle S \rangle / R$ (where you view $R \subset \mathbb{Z}\langle S \rangle \subset \mathbb{Q}\langle S \rangle$ in the obvious way). The result is divisible, and the obvious map is injective.

It's best to work this out on example. If $G = \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}\langle x \rangle / 0$, then $I = \mathbb{Q}\langle x \rangle / (0) = \mathbb{Q}$. If $G = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}\langle x \rangle / (nx)$, then $I = \mathbb{Q} \langle x \rangle / \langle nx \rangle = \mathbb{Q}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The result is quite different from $G \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ (in fact $G \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is a quotient of $I$: it's $I / (R \otimes \mathbb{Q})$).

Comment: Isn't ${\mathbb Q}\langle S\rangle/R \cong {\mathbb Z}\langle S\rangle/R\otimes{\mathbb Q}$? I don't see a straightforward construction like this which would e.g. yield ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ from ${\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @Hanno No, actually $(\mathbb{Z}\langle S  \rangle / R) \otimes \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}\langle S \rangle / (R \otimes \mathbb{Q})$. The difference is important. The presentation of $I$ isn't a presentation of $\mathbb{Q}$-modules, it's really the quotient of the abelian group $\mathbb{Q}\langle S \rangle$ by the abelian group $R$, the same one that appears in the presentation of $G$. If you apply it to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} \langle x \rangle / (nx)$ then you get $\mathbb{Q} / n \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant you'd take the ${\mathbb Q}$-span of $R$. Thanks, the way it's written now it's very clear.